# Port Forward Not Working in MiniKube on Windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am setting up kubernetes on my Laptop (Windows 10 OS) to work on the Containers and it's Orchestration. **I have created Minikube VM using the below command and it got succeeded.**

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch"
```

I am able to Launch Kubernetes and **able to launch the Minikube dashboard as well**

I started the Kubernetes cluster and deployed nginx app into Cluster. Below are the commands.

```
kubectl run hello-nginx --image=nginx --port=8020
kubectl expose deployment hello-nginx --type=NodePort --port=8020 --target-port=8020
```

I am able to view PODs and Services using the below commands.

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl get services
```

**it works perfect up to here**. I am able to view deployment, PODs and Service information in the Minikube dashboard.

When i run the below command to launch the application in the browser, browser is throwing a message as "Resource Not Found" but I am able to view POD and Service information in the MiniKube Dashboard.

```
minikube service hello-nginx
```

URL: http://192.168.43.20:32087/

getting exception in a browser

```
This website could not be found.
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
```

Below given the deployment YAML file,

```
{
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "hello-nginx",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/hello-nginx",
    "uid": "5629038e-93e5-11e9-ad2e-00155d162e0e",
    "resourceVersion": "49313",
    "generation": 1,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-06-21T05:28:01Z",
    "labels": {
      "run": "hello-nginx"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "run": "hello-nginx"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "run": "hello-nginx"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "hello-nginx",
            "image": "nginx",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 8020,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "strategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "maxUnavailable": 1,
        "maxSurge": 1
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 2147483647,
    "progressDeadlineSeconds": 2147483647
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 1,
    "replicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "readyReplicas": 1,
    "availableReplicas": 1,
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Available",
        "status": "True",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2019-06-21T05:28:01Z",
        "lastTransitionTime": "2019-06-21T05:28:01Z",
        "reason": "MinimumReplicasAvailable",
        "message": "Deployment has minimum availability."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below given the replica set YAML file info,

```
{
  "kind": "ReplicaSet",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "hello-nginx-76696c698f",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/hello-nginx-76696c698f",
    "uid": "562be1e8-93e5-11e9-ad2e-00155d162e0e",
    "resourceVersion": "49310",
    "generation": 3,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-06-21T05:28:01Z",
    "labels": {
      "pod-template-hash": "76696c698f",
      "run": "hello-nginx"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/desired-replicas": "1",
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/max-replicas": "2",
      "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1"
    },
    "ownerReferences": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
        "kind": "Deployment",
        "name": "hello-nginx",
        "uid": "5629038e-93e5-11e9-ad2e-00155d162e0e",
        "controller": true,
        "blockOwnerDeletion": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "pod-template-hash": "76696c698f",
        "run": "hello-nginx"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "pod-template-hash": "76696c698f",
          "run": "hello-nginx"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "hello-nginx",
            "image": "nginx",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 8020,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {},
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "fullyLabeledReplicas": 1,
    "readyReplicas": 1,
    "availableReplicas": 1,
    "observedGeneration": 3
  }
}
```

Now I am trying out the Port Forwarding option to route the request to POD, but it is not working.

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/hello-nginx 8020:8020
```

I am getting the below exception when i try to access the URL "http://127.0.0.1:8020"

```
Handling connection for 8020
E0622 01:07:06.306320   18888 portforward.go:331] an error occurred forwarding 8020 -> 8020: error forwarding port 8020 to pod c54d6faaa545992dce02f58490a26154134843eb7426a51e78df2cda172b514c, uid : exit status 1: 2019/06/21 08:01:18 socat[4535] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8020, 16): Connection refused
```

I have read many articles on this but couldn't found the root cause for this issue. Am i missing anything important here?

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is actually unrelated to Minikube or port forwarding. You expose the port `8020`, however the application `hello-nginx` uses `80`. So you should use `80` everywhere instead of `8020`. For example:

```
kubectl run hello-nginx --image=nginx --port=80
```

---

Saying that, using Minikube is not the best option for Windows. Much better is to use [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop), then everything you run on Kubernetes is available on your `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. **Port=80 is working for nginx**. i created an API (my project API) before i creating "nginx" to check whether service is getting exposed. **I tried to expose my api as i did for "nginx" but it is not getting exposed**. below given the code, not sure why my service is not exposed, however i am able to view deployments and services in my dashboard. Is there anything am I missing here to expose my api container?  `kubectl run retailapicontainer --image=myapiinkube --port=8500` and `kubectl expose deployment retailapicontainer --type=NodePort`

Comment: It looks fine what you do. Could you paste here the result of `kubectl describe services <service-name>`?

Comment: Thanks for yours reply. Please find the result. **`Name:retailapicontainer
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=retailapicontainer
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=retailapicontainer
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.110.142.14
Port:                     <unset>  8500/TCP
TargetPort:               8500/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31590/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.5:8500
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>`**

Comment: Hi Rafal Leszko, **As you mentioned**, i have enabled kubernetes in docker desktop and deployed the service. Dashboard is showing successful deployments but not able to access the service. Here is the description of my service. `Name: retailapicontainer
Namespace: default
Labels: run=retailapicontainer
Annotations: <none>
Selector:run=retailapicontainer
Type:  NodePort
IP: 10.96.173.12
LoadBalancer Ingress:localhost
Port: <unset> 8090/TCP
TargetPort:8090/TCP
NodePort:<unset>32443/TCP
Endpoints:10.1.0.9:8090
Session Affinity:None
External Traffic Policy: Cluster
Events: <none>`

Comment: Your configuration looks fine. TBH I cannot reproduce your issue. If the port 80 works fine, but 8090 does not, it may be related to your application itself. Could you share it?

Comment: Hi Rafal Leszko, I zipped & uploaded the sample code in this path. This is startup code `https://github.com/rajswastik1986/mydotnetcoreapi/blob/master/MyServiceAPI.zip` let me know if you have any challenges in downloading the code. I am developing API Project using .Net Core. You can find the dockerfile inside the project folder. **Instead of kubectl**, if i use docker command `docker run -d -p 5079:80 --name retailapicontainer myapiinkube` I am able to access the site `http://localhost:5079/api/values`. Please let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Using Docker, you expose the port `80`, but using kubernetes you expose `8090`. Why is it so?

Comment: Hi Rafal Leszko, There is no explicit reason behind in exposing the **80** port for docker and **8090** for kube. Do you think, it will be the reason for not able to access the URL using Kibectl? If so, please let me know the right way to do it using Kubectl. Thanks for your time. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Hi Rafal Leszko, I deployed my api container on **80 Port** in kubernetes, it started working:) Since my container on kubernetes is working, i will mark this as answer. Just wanted to know **Do you any idea why only 80 port is accessible for me in kubernetes?** Thanks for your suggestion and putting me in the right way to find the root cause.

Comment: Hi, It's hard to tell. NodePort service does not make any distinctions between port 80 or any other. I tried other ports and they all worked fine for me.